# How to modify UI's views in other thread different than the main one due to heavy modifications

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-anr-dialog

I have the following problem. I'm working on a mobile solution that consumes data from a server. For thoses HTTP transactions I obviously use an AsyncTask in order to separate this communication task from the main thread. However, after a successful response I need to build a Really Big Table Layout (with 2000 - 10000 table rows or more) to insert all the records coming inside the data. So if I start to build the table in the main thread I'll always get a ANR problem (Application Not Responding Dialog).

On the other hand, it's widely known that I cannot modify/add/touch elements from a different thread that is not the UI thread, so I have not been able to do this heavy table processing.

Suggesstions are heard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "with 2000 - 10000 table rows or more" -- this is a **very** bad idea. First, you will run out of heap space, as you will be consuming multiple MB just in `TableRow` widgets, let alone the contents, let alone the model data you are using to populate the contents. Second, you are causing the very performance problem that you are worried about. The user can only see a few rows at a time. Whether you use `ListView`, `GridView`, or `RecyclerView`, **please** only instantiate a handful of rows and swap between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive it with pagination, you can show 20 rows first, when you scroll down and reach the bottom, add the other block of 20 elements and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask` to accomplish this? You can do all of the heavy processing in `doInBackground`, and then when you are done, simply update the UI in `onPostExecute`, which runs on the UI `Thread`. You can find more information on `AsyncTask` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html